# MATLAB - Create img from linear index array + color

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, indexing

I have a blank img containing all zeros of size x, y, 3.
I have an array of linear indices e.g.

```
[1 10 99 1562]
```

I have a color as a 1, 1, 3 double array e.g.

```
color(:,:,1) = 100
color(:, :, 2) = 200
color(:,:,3) = 100
```

How can I set all indices of the img to that color?

Comment: The term 'linear indices' is wrong for what you're saying. But I understand what you're asking

Comment: What would these types of indices be called? I created them using sub2ind so I just assumed I was creating linear indices? Also could you help me set the values

Comment: Can i get some more info please

Comment: Probably 'Linear indices of single color channel of an image' be the better term for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a loop:

```
[r, c] = ind2sub(size(A(:,:,1)),ind); %Getting corresponding row and column subscripts
for k = 1:numel(ind)
    A(r(k),c(k),:) = color;           %Changing each of them to desired color
end
```

or a vectorised solution:

```
%Creating a mask
mask = false(size(A(:,:,1)));   mask(ind) = true;
%Transferring the color to the mask
A = mask.*color;    %Impl.exp., use A = bsxfun(@times,mask,color) in <R2016b
```